# Is it possible to update fetched data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have written some code that gets loggings from a database, processes them and if something goes wrong, an error-message is written in the database.
In the end of the code I remove all the loggings from the database where the error field (in the database) is null.

```
            var logs = ctx.Logs.Where(record => String.IsNullOrEmpty(record.Error))
                        .Where(record => !Beingprocessed.Contains(record))
                        .Take(100)
                        .ToArray();
```

The fetching/processing/deleting is done in multiple threads at once, so records can be removed by another thread from the database while this code is running. Is there a possibility to just update `logs` with the values from the database?

Something like

```
logs.Update();
ctx.Logs.RemoveRange(logs.Where(l => l.Error == null));
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

(I know I can just use the ID's from `logs` etc. to fetch them again but I want to know if there is anything that exists to update entities you fetched from database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
ctx.Entry(Logs).Reload();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I'm looking for. Too bad you can't pass an array to it.